# Is this coercive function?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Given a function $f(a) = a^4 +a^3 +2a^2 +a+1$ . How can I show that it is a coercive function? I am having a hard time understanding how to calculate the norm of $f$ in order to show that f is coercive. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of coercive that you're using? Is it as simple as $f(x) \to \infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$?

Comment: Yes, that is the same definition I'm using.

Comment: So, I take it it's not sufficient to observe that $f$ is an even polynomial with a positive leading coefficient? Do you want, for example, an $\varepsilon$-$N$ style proof?

Comment: Yes, ε -N style proof would also be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x^2 + x + 1 \\
&= x^2(x^2 + x + 1) + x^2 + x + 1 \\
&= (x^2 + 1)(x^2 + x + 1).
\end{align*}
Further, note that
$$x^2 + x + 1 = x^2 + x + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} = \left(x + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4} \ge \frac{3}{4},$$
and $x^2 + 1 > 0$, hence
$$f(x) \ge \frac{3}{4}(x^2 + 1) \ge \frac{3}{4}x^2.$$
Now, this tells me that, given $M > 0$, we can choose $N = \frac{2\sqrt{M}}{\sqrt{3}}$, and get
\begin{align*}
|x| \ge N &\implies |x| \ge \frac{2\sqrt{M}}{\sqrt{3}} \\
&\implies x^2 \ge \frac{4M}{3} \\
&\implies \frac{3}{4}x^2 \ge M \\
&\implies f(x) \ge M.
\end{align*}
Thus, $f(x) \to \infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$.